# 404 ! when tried to open uploaded file in dam

Tags: adobe, aem

I uploaded some files in CRXDE Dam using 'Asset Manager' and file is successfully got uploaded into dam. When i try to open the using in jsp , im getting 404 ! error. In jsp I'm giving the path as 
""
Where,
${podfiles.path} ->/content/dam/nextgen/Ehub-POD/IN/2.pdf
When i click this icon it should open the pdf file. It was working fine, suddenly for some data its not working and later its not working for ny pdf file.

Regards,
Nandhini [Image Attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqBvC.png)

[Attached CRXDE nod image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHm7y.png)

Comment: Did you verified wether your content node is present related to that path in your CRX?

Comment: yes , the content is there in CXDE, please find the attachements

Comment: What about the jcr content binary data for that pdf.? If you try to download it and open is it opens pdf back?

Comment: yes, when i try to download it open as PDF in web, can i know why im getting 404 ! even though the file is available in dam path

Comment: Hmm, any errors in your console or error.log file? When you try to access via jsp?

Comment: 09.03.2017 09:47:40.948 *ERROR* [145.26.81.167 [1489049260946] GET /bin/receive HTTP/1.1] org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.security.authentication.external.impl.ExternalLoginModule No IDP found with name ldaps. Will not be used for login.
09.03.2017 09:47:49.610 *ERROR* [10.121.247.80 [1489049269586] GET /content/dam/nextgen/Ehub-POD/IN/2.pdf HTTP/1.1] org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.security.authentication.external.impl.ExternalLoginModule No IDP found with name ldaps. Will not be used for login.

Comment: One more Check :-         09.03.2017 10:20:33.105 *ERROR* [10.121.247.80 [1489051233088] GET /content/dam/nextgen/Ehub-POD/USNY/Sample%20POD.pdf HTTP/1.1] org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.spi.security.authentication.external.impl.ExternalLoginModule No IDP found with name ldaps. Will not be used for login.

Comment: From your logs, Looks like authentication access issue, are you using any LDAP? What is the user you have logged in? Did it work with admin user?

Comment: But I'm using admin session to get the details from dam , in the same way while uploading also, so access is there for all the user

Comment: can any one help me on this, 404 ! issue